# Does varying evening exposure to blue light sabotage a consistent sleep/wake schedule?

Tags: neuroscience, sleep

Sleep hygiene measures include keeping a consistent bed time and, more importantly, wake time [(Chaput et al., 2020)](https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/full/10.1139/apnm-2020-0032). It is also suggested to minimize exposure to evening blue light [(Chellappa et al., 2013)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/jsr.12050). Due to melatonin suppression, blue light also induces a circadian phase delay, shifting one's circadian rhythm to a further point [(Moderie et al., 2017)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1389945717301582).

The study by Chaput et al. mentioned later sleep times and sleep variability as impacting sleep quality negatively. Melatonin suppression induces these indirectly through phase delay, and potentially, by promoting circadian irregularity [(Arendt, 2019)](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fendo.2019.00391/full).

Am I right in concluding that despite a consistent bed time, varying exposure time to evening blue light (e.g. alternating between 3h exposure and no exposure) will likely affect circadian rhythm and sleep quality, independently of one's actual sleep schedule? Can circadian rhythm be delayed and affect sleep quality *despite* identical sleep and wake times? Or are the circadian effects of melatonin mediated *through* such shifts in sleep times?